# How to abstract over a "back and forth" transformation?

Tags: haskell

Consider this example (from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23456/crtitique-my-haskell-function-capitalize):

```
import Data.Char

capWord [] = []
capWord (h:t) = toUpper h : map toLower t

capitalize = unwords . map capWord . words
```

Is there a good way to abstract over the "back and forth" transformation, e.g. `unwords . f . words`? The best I could come up was

```
class Lift a b | a -> b where
  up :: a -> b
  down :: b -> a

instance Lift String [String] where
  up = words
  down = unwords

lifted :: (Lift a b) => (b -> b) -> a -> a
lifted f = down . f . up

capitalize = lifted (map capWord)
```

but it feels not very flexible, and needs `MultiParamTypeClasses`, `FunctionalDependencies`, `TypeSynonymInstances` and `FlexibleInstances` - which might be an indicator that it goes *slightly* over the top.

Comment: You don't need the functional dependency there, which makes everything quite a bit more flexible. I'd still agree with Cat Plus Plus that this doesn't buy you much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say the best answer is "no, because abstracting over that doesn't buy you anything". In fact your solution is far less flexible: there can be only one instance of `Lift String [String]` in scope and there are more ways to split string into a list of strings than just `words/unwords` (which means you'll start throwing newtypes or even more arcane extensions into the mix). Keep it simple — the original `capitalize` is just fine the way it is.

Or, if you really insist:

```
lifted :: (a -> b, b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
lifted (up, down) f = down . f . up

onWords = lifted (words, unwords)
onLines = lifted (lines, unlines)

capitalize = onWords $ map capWord
```

Conceptually the same thing as your typeclass, except without abusing typeclass machinery so much.

Comment: This is effectively just an easier to understand, less general version of DarkOtter's answer. It has the same minor flaw, too.

Answer (score 43):

Your `lifted` is actually the same as `dimap` from [`Data.Profunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/profunctors/3.1.2/doc/html/Data-Profunctor.html):

```
onWords = dimap words unwords
capitalize = onWords (map capWord)
```

That might not be the direction of generalization you thought about. But look at the type of the equivalent function in [`Control.Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/latest/doc/html/Control-Functor.html) from `category-extras`:

```
dimap :: Bifunctor f (Dual k) k k => k b a -> k c d -> k (f a c) (f b d)
```

This version generalizes it over everything which is both a `QFunctor` and a co-`PFunctor`. Not *that* useful in everyday scenarios, but interesting.

Comment: Best answer, plus also the first understandable Profunctor example I have met.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a lens for this. Lenses are quite a lot more general than this I think, but anything where you have such bidirectional functions can be made into a lens.

For example, given `words` and `unwords`, we can make a `worded` lens:

```
worded :: Simple Iso String [String]
worded = iso words unwords
```

Then you can use it to apply a function inside the lens, e.g. `lifted f x` becomes `(worded %~ f) x`. The only downside of lenses is that the library is extremely complicated, and has many obscure operators like `%~`, even though the core idea of a lens is actually quite simple.

### EDIT: This is not an isomorphism

I had incorrectly assumed that `unwords . words` is equivalent to the identity function, and it is not, because extra spaces between words are lost, as correctly pointed out by several people.

Instead, we could use a much more complicated lens, like the following, which does preserve the spacing between words. Although I think it's still not an isomorphism, this does at least mean that `x == (x & worded %~ id)`, I hope. It is on the other hand, not in the least a very nice way of doing things, and not very efficient. It is possible that an indexed lens of the words themselves (rather than a list of the words) may be better, although it permits fewer operations (I think, it's really hard to tell when lenses are involved).

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Control.Lens

worded :: Simple Lens String [String]
worded f s =
    let p = makeParts s
    in fmap (joinParts p) (f (takeParts p))

data Parts = End | Space Char Parts | Word String Parts

makeParts :: String -> Parts
makeParts = startPart
    where
      startPart [] = End
      startPart (c:cs) =
          if isSpace c then Space c (startPart cs) else joinPart (Word . (c:)) cs

      joinPart k [] = k [] End
      joinPart k (c:cs) =
          if isSpace c then k [] (Space c (startPart cs)) else joinPart (k . (c:)) cs

takeParts :: Parts -> [String]
takeParts End = []
takeParts (Space _ t) = takeParts t
takeParts (Word s t) = s : takeParts t

joinParts :: Parts -> [String] -> String
joinParts _ [] = []
joinParts (Word _ End) (ws@(_:_:_)) = unwords ws
joinParts End ws = unwords ws
joinParts (Space c t) ws = c : joinParts t ws
joinParts (Word _ t) (w:ws) = w ++ joinParts t ws
```

Comment: But that's not an isomorphism... =(

Comment: Is it not? Damn, I thought I was almost understanding a part of the lens package. My bad, please feel free to correct the answer.

Comment: It would "sort of" work, except that it'll take "foo     bar" -> "foo bar".

Comment: That said, there is almost definitely a `Lens`-type thing for it. Perhaps a `Prism`.

Comment: Sorry @tel, I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: @DarkOtter Try running `unwords (words "I     have    spaces")` in GHCI. I suspect @tel's comment said basically the same thing. Unfortunately the Stack Overflow software automatically removes multiple spaces in comments! I ended up pasting in some unicode en-quads.

Comment: Oh, SO ate my spaces, `"foo\ \ \ \ bar" -> "foo\ bar"`

Comment: Take a look at my answer further down that uses `Prism'`s. It's kind of unsatisfactory since it's confusing, but it respects the actual transformations a bit better.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Ah, I see, I didn't realise words and unwords did that. I think I see why it's not an isomorphism then, I had assumed that `unwords . words` was equivalent to `id`.

Comment: @tel Thanks, that looks like a good answer, although I have to admit I'm still fairly hazy on Prism's :P You're absolutely right though, I had (incorrectly it turns out) assumed that `unwords . words` was an identity, and it is not. I might be inclined to say that in this case the best approach may be to make a version that is actually an isomorphism.

Comment: @DarkOtter There are [other](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-1.1.4.3) libraries which make lenses quite easier to approach and use.

Comment: @DarkOtter Something like `unwords' :: String -> [Either Int String]` could be used to create a true isomorphism (at least on Latin 1).

Answer (score 8):

Like DarkOtter suggested, Edward Kmett's [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library has you covered, but `Lens` is too weak and `Iso` is *slightly* too strong since `unwords . words` isn't an identity. You could try a `Prism` instead.

```
wordPrism :: Prism' String [String]
wordPrism = prism' unwords $ \s ->
   -- inefficient, but poignant
   if s == (unwords . words) s then Just (words s) else Nothing
```

Now you can define `capitalize` as

```
capitalize' :: String -> String
capitalize' = wordPrism %~ map capWord
-- a.k.a    = over wordPrism (map capWord)
```

but this has fairly pathological default behavior for your case. For `String`s which can't be mapped as isomorphisms (strings with multiple spaces in a row inside of them) `over wordPrism g == id`. There ought to be an "over if possible" operator for `Prism`s, but I don't know of one. You could define it though:

```
overIfPossible :: Prism s t a b -> (a -> b) -> (s -> Maybe t)
overIfPossible p f s = if (isn't p s) then Nothing else Just (over p f s)

capitalize :: String -> Maybe String
capitalize = wordPrism `overIfPossible` map capWord
```

---

Now, really, both of these are pretty unsatisfactory since what you really want is to capitalize all words and retain the spacing. For this `(words, unwords)` is too weak generally due to the non-existence of isomorphism that I've highlighted above. You'd have to write your own custom machinery which maintains spaces after which you'd have an `Iso` and could use DarkOtter's answer directly.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed not flexible enough! How would you lift a function to work on a line-by-line basis? You're going to need a `newtype` wrapper for that! Like so

```
newtype LineByLine = LineByLine { unLineByLine :: String }

instance Lift LineByLine [String] where
    up = lines . unLineByLine
    down = LineByLine . unlines
```

But now there is no good reason to prefer the word-by-word version over the line-by-line one.

I would just use `unwords . map f . words`, to me that's the idiomatic "Apply f to all the words and put them back together". If you do this more often, consider writing a function.