# Generalized `fold` or how to perform `fold` and `map` at a time

Tags: haskell, category-theory

(Apology by the title, I can't do better)

My question is to find some generalized struct or "standard" function to perform the next thing:

```
xmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> g b
```

then, we can map not only elements, by also the entire struct.

Some (not real) example

```
xmap id myBinaryTree :: [a]
```

at the moment, I must to do a explicit structure conversor (typical `fromList`, `toList`) then

```
toList . fmap id   -- if source struct has map
fmap id . fromList -- if destination struct has map
```

(to perform `toStruct`, `fromStruct` I use `fold`).

Exists some way to generalize `to`/`from` structs? (should be)
Exists that function (`xmap`)?

Thank you!! :)

Comment: Is the [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) is something like what are you looking for?

Comment: @m0nhawk, looks fine (+1), be monoid is a reasonable restriction, maybe exists some more general? (if not, it would be the solution :)

Comment: That's depend on what the `a`, `b`, `f` and `g` is. I don't think there is something more general. But, you can check [`Hoogle`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+f+a+-%3E+g+b) for more.

Comment: Looks like a [Profunctor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15235409/1346276).

Comment: @joseJuan foldMap is as general as it gets.  Just have your target data structure implement Monoid, and most of them already do (like lists).

Comment: @m0nhawk I was looking for @tel type response but your `foldMap` is very closed to practical application. If you wish, write as answer to accept it, please and thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to add to [tel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841473/1333025) (I got my idea only after reading it) that in many cases you can make general natural transformation that will work similarly to `foldMap`. If we can use `foldMap`, we know that `f` is `Foldable`. Then we need some way how to constructs elements of `g a` and combine them together. We can use `Alternative` for that, it has all we need (`pure`, `empty` and `<|>`), although we could also construct some less general type class for this purpose (we don't need `<*>` anywhere).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, RankNTypes #-}
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable

type f :~> g = forall a. f a -> g a

nt :: (Functor f, Foldable f, Alternative g) => f :~> g
nt = foldr ((<|>) . pure) empty
```

Then using tel's `xmap`

```
xmap :: (a -> b) -> (f :~> g) -> (f a -> g b)
xmap f n = map f . n
```

we can do things like

```
> xmap (+1) nt (Just 1) :: [Int]
[2]
```

Comment: Haha—I added a comment on my answer simultaneously with this. Your answer provides much more depth, though. +1

Comment: Really, all responses are great, I think Petr's answer is the best candidate to be accepted, is practical and closed to theory (although I'd like accept all :D)

Comment: @josejuan I'd rather like if you accepted tel's answer - my only builds on his and I wouldn't get the idea without having seen his.

Comment: I was thinking on "first readers", I suggest to you refer @tel response into your answer (to me their "natural..." explanation was illuminating).

Comment: Feel free to incorporate any important details from mine to yours. I think it's best to have a maximally comprehensive answer and mine does end shy of the "folding" aspect since there are so many non-folding natural transformations.

Answer (score 5):

As `f` and `g` are functors, a [natural transformation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.1/doc/html/Control-Functor-Extras.html) is what you're looking for (see also [You Could Have Defined Natural Transformations](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/05/you-could-have-defined-natural.html)). So a transformation like

```
f :~> g = forall a. f a -> g a
```

is needed to create xmap which is then just

```
xmap :: (a -> b) -> (f :~> g) -> (f a -> g b)
xmap f n = map f . n
```

You still need to define types of `(f :~> g)`, but there' not a general way of doing that.

Comment: #tel your response close to my search (clarify me a lot... I think :) "natural..."), I'm doubting between your theorical response and @m0nhawk practicals, I can't accept both! :D, thanks a lot to all! :)

Comment: Glad this was useful. I'll add quickly that `foldMap` can be viewed as a natural transformation as well. Define `newtype Id a = Id a` to be "the most boring functor" and `foldMap :: Monoid m => f m -> m` is a natural translation `(f :~> Id)`. It implies more than that though since it promises to fold all your values together, while there are plenty of `(f :~> Id)`s that do nothing interesting.

Comment: Sorry, `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m` isn't quite what you'd need. You need `fold :: Monoid m => f m -> m` which is like `fold :: Monoid m => (f :~> Id) m`.

Comment: Oh, and funny story about "natural". They're called that because they were invented before anything else in category theory. The idea arises as a kind of "natural" thing in algebraic topology that Eilenberg and MacLane wanted to generalize. To do so they invented Functors which needed a place to live, so they focused on and developed Categories.

Comment: Also worth a look: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category_theory/Natural_transformation